# yii2 - Get URL Parameter

Tags: php, url, parameters, yii2

I have a question. How to get date_from and date_to value from a URL in my view. I try to use 
`Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('date_from')` but not get anything.

The URL:

```
localhost/..../index.php?r=installment%2Freport&InstallmentSearch%5Bdate_from%5D=2017-11-27&InstallmentSearch%5Bdate_to%5D=2017-11-27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestion**

```
if ($searchModel->load(Yii::$app->request->get())) {
    $dateFrom = $searchModel->date_from;
    $dateTo = $searchModel->date_to;
}
```

**Using `QueryParam()`**

```
Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('InstallmentSearch')['date_from'];
```

Comment: I have similar kind of issue can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73581066/6854117)?